# Understanding joins: Listing categories without specified product

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to MySQL, trying to understand how join works.
I have two tables: `categories` and `products` each with `id` and `name` fields.
Third table is product_to_category (many to many) with `category_id` and `product_id`.

I wanted to list all categories containing specified product (with id = 5).
To do this, I made a following query:

```
        SELECT `categories`.`id`, `categories`.`name`
        FROM `categories`
        LEFT JOIN `product_to_category`
        ON `categories`.`id` = `product_to_category`.`category_id`
        WHERE `product_to_category`.`product_id` = 5
```

I am wondering if it is possible to something opposite: to list all categories which does not contains specified product?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a _many-to-many_ relation? I would make two tables: `categories` (with `id`) as master table and `products` (with `id` and `category_id`) as details table. What do you think?

Comment: Not exactly, because I would like to have one product in many different categories and each category can have many products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `not exists` operator for this:

```
SELECT c.`id`, c.`name`
FROM   `categories` c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   `product_to_category` ptc
                   WHERE  c.`id` = ptc.`category_id` AND 
                          ptc.`product_id` = 5)
```